# Difference between onKeyPress and onKeyUp

Tags: javascript, web

I am trying to figure out what the difference is between onKeyPress and onKeyUp.  I know that onKeyPress happens before the action was submitted and onKeyUp happens after.

My problem is what happens when the enter button is pressed?

If I use onKeyPress my code works fine and the submit button is disabled. If I use onKeyUp it will submit it, but the submit button will still be active for some reason.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function InformUser()
{
    window.document.getElementById("loadingMessageDIV").style.display = "block";
   <%=Page.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSubmit as Control)%>
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
}

function validateTxt() {
    var input = document.getElementById("<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>").value;
    if(input.length > 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
    }
}

</script>
```

Here is the textbox that calls validateTxt()

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Font-Size="11pt" 
                onkeyup="validateTxt()"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is the submit button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="InformUser();" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
                            Text="Login" Font-Bold="True"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
 </script>
```

So to recap: If I change onkeypress to onkeyup I gain the ability to captures backspaces, but when I press enter the submit button is still active.

If I change onkeyup to onkeypress then I gain the ability to press enter and have the submit button be deactivated.  Downside is I can't capture backspaces.

Thanks!

### Solution:

Figured it out thanks to apsillers.

I had to use onkeyup with a check agaisnt the enter key

```
function validateTxt(event) {
    var input = document.getElementById("<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>").value;
    var key = event.keyCode || event.which;  
    if(input.length > 0 && key != 13)
    {
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't onkeydown capture all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun fact: the [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onkeypress) event is not part of any standard, so browser vendors are free make it behave however they like.  Coventionally, though, `keypress` only fires for keys that have a printable representation.  If you want to capture nonprintable key presses (arrow keys, control keys, backspace, etc.), you want `keyup` (or `keydown`).

Couldn't you use `onkeydown`?  Or use `onkeyup` and check for the Enter key (`e.keyCode` 13)?

Other notes:

`keypress` and `keydown` will fire repeatedly as a key is held down, whereas `keyup` only fires once.

MDN has a handy comprehensive [KeyboardEvent guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/KeyboardEvent#Processing_of_key_events) with more information.

Comment: This worked all I had to do was use onkeyup with checking agaisnt the enter key.
`function validateTxt(event) {
        var input = document.getElementById("<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>").value;
        var key = event.keyCode || event.which;  
        if(input.length > 0 && key != 13)
        {
            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 3):

- onKeyPress is fired when any key on your keyboard is pressed
- onKeyUp is fired when you release the key on your keyboard. If you press any
  key and do not release it, onKeyPress will be fired but nor onKeyUp

Probably you would prefer perform validations [onSubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp) in your form.

Answer (score 0):

`keypress` only works for alphabets, numbers and symbols without metakey
`keyup` works for all keys on keyboard​​​​​

Used jQuery in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/jCHf6/)